# Apply function by extracting values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas dataframe. I would like to apply a function on an old dataframe (df1) by extracting values from another dataframe (df2).

DF2 looks like this (the actual one has ~500 rows)

```
  Judge     old_court_name        new_court_name
  John      eighth circuit        first circuit
  Ruth      us court claims.      fifth circuit
  Ben      district connecticut  district ohio
```

Then I've written a function

```
def addJudgeCourt(df1, Judge, old_court_name, new_court_name):
```

How do I tell pandas to extract the last three items by iterating from the dataframe2? Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me, if the rows in the tables refer to the same index. In such a case, pd.concat([df1,df2[["Judge", "old_court_name", "new_court_name']]], axis=1) should be enough. Otherwise you need to join the tables by pd.merge

Comment: Pls explain better what you are trying to do